# How can an adult be bitten by a snake without feeling it?

Tags: snakes, india

Assume that the victim is a healthy rational adult.

I've chanced on snakes while trekking in nature. So I was stunned to read about [this tragedy](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-44253586) where:

> Not realising she had been attacked, the woman began breastfeeding her child. Both died before they could reach a hospital.

Am I correct to infer that lethal snakebites can yet be painless and slight?

Comment: I have a friend who was bitten by a poisonous snake and did not realize the fact until his leg swelled up.

Comment: The article is been updated to say: "The incident was reported by Indian police but experts have cast doubt on the manner of transmission of the venom."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the bite of a common krait (*Bungarus caeruleus*) can be painless.  It is a venomous snake found on the subcontinent of India and is also known as the Indian krait.  Kraits are nocturnal, therefore instances with humans most often occur at night and therefore the snake may also not be seen.

[image]

Source: [Common krait (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_krait)